# ios : UIScrollView with UITableView

Tags: ios6

I want to implement one page with vertical scroll view which contains some Images, Labels and one table view in bottom.

Table may have any number of rows. When user scroll to the top other elements such as images, labels should be hide but table should be visible at the top of screen and only table items should be scrolled.

I have tried by setting the currentoffset of scrollview in method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` but its not such smooth.

Scroll view first goes above, comes down and then set the table at top.

Can you please suggest me what should i implement here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
// Add image in scrollView
serviceImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row.png"]];
[serviceImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
serviceImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 100);
[myScrollView addSubview:serviceImage];
[serviceImage release];

// Add label in scrollView
UILabel *rateLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 105, 300, 20)];
rateLbl.text = @"Rates";
rateLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
rateLbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244/255.0 green:29/255.0 blue:94/255.0 alpha:1.0];
rateLbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
rateLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[myScrollView addSubview:rateLbl];
[rateLbl release];

// Add table in scrollView
int heightRateTbl;
heightRateTbl = [productType count] * 44;
rateTableView.frame =CGRectMake(10, expectedLabelSize.height + expectedDecLblSize.height + heightDayTbl + 555, 300, heightRateTbl);  
rateTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
rateTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[rateTableView reloadData];

You can enable or disable scroll according your choice.

// Set scrollView height
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 125 + heightRateTbl);
```

Do not forget to set delegates and declare all things(in .h file and in .xib file).

Hope i helped.

Comment: thanks for responding,

I was doing the same but problem was bouncing scroll view.
self.scrollView.bounces = NO; helped me and now scroll view is working fine but some times it stops scrolling, working on that.

Comment: I am unable to see any link to accept the answer, please suggest me.